# How to make content dialog background consistent?

Tags: winui-3, contentdialog

I would like the background color of the dialog content and the background color behind the buttons to be the same:

[image: content dialog]

How can I do this?

My xaml:

```xaml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3BlankAppVS2022.ContentDialogContent"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock
            Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipisicing elit."
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

My C#:

```cs
private async void ShowDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
    dialog.Title = "Save your work?";
    dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Save";
    dialog.SecondaryButtonText = "Don't Save";
    dialog.CloseButtonText = "Cancel";
    dialog.DefaultButton = ContentDialogButton.Primary;
    dialog.XamlRoot = Content.XamlRoot;
    dialog.Content = new ContentDialogContent();
    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve this is to set the `ContentDialogTopOverlay` and `ContentDialogSeparatorBorderBrush` theme resources to `null`:

```cs
private async void ShowDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
    dialog.Title = "Save your work?";
    dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Save";
    dialog.SecondaryButtonText = "Don't Save";
    dialog.CloseButtonText = "Cancel";
    dialog.DefaultButton = ContentDialogButton.Primary;
    dialog.XamlRoot = Content.XamlRoot;
    Application.Current.Resources["ContentDialogTopOverlay"] = null;
    Application.Current.Resources["ContentDialogSeparatorBorderBrush"] = null;
    dialog.Content = new ContentDialogContent();
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

The other option is to create a custom template for the `ContentDialog`.

Comment: Setting the two theme resources works great. Thanks!